# How does one run a .jar file in S60 OS?

Tags: java, symbian, nokia, n73

I want to run a .jar file on my Nokia N73 phone. I cannot figure out what I need to do this.
I have downloaded the Sun Java Wireless Kit but that just connects to its own emulators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to transfer and install that file to the mobile phone.
You have few options here:

1. Install Nokia PC Suite and use it's Application Installer to transfer JAR file to the phone.
2. Send it by bluetooth to the phone
3. Upload the jar file to some file hosting service and browse to it from the phone

All this considering that your file is a Java application for mobile (J2ME)

Answer (score 1):

I would add

4. copy the .jar file to a memory card and simply open it in the phone file manager

to Vitaly Polonetsky's answer.

As a general rule, J2ME applications should be deployed as a .jad file, not a .jar file.

a .jad file is a simple, much smaller, text file that contains an http:// link to the jar file, for the phone web browser to download and install. a .jad file also allows the application to be signed so you can extend it the benefit of the doubt when it tries to access the mobile network or your phone's memory.